# Video conferencing server for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, video-conferencing

so, I'm setting up a virtualized environment running on Hyper-V and I'm looking to see if there's a video conferencing system that can be setup on a virtual server, prererably for Windows Server 2008 R2. I'm not sure if his is possible, but is there something that can be done through IIS Media Services?

Answer (score 1):

You could install the [GNU Gatekeeper](http://www.gnugk.org/) on the server so H.323 video-conferencing terminals can connect.

But beware that virtual machines usually don't provide the same even latency that real servers do, so you should avoid proxying RTP through virtual machines with whatever system you end up using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try TrueConf Server as far as I remember it works on Hyper V. Be sure that your server is not overloaded otherwise any video conferencing software server will not work properly.

Comment: Greetings person with same name. I looked at the TrueConf Server and it looks nice, but it is painfully expensive... Good thing this is not a mission critical need for us at the moment, but I'll definitely explore it more in the future when we need it. Thanks!